# TextView not updating in onResume in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout, onresume

I my code I am having issues with the textview , it is not updating when the main activity resumes.  Basically it has a textview and a button. When the program loads it reads the date from a sharedpreferences file and sets the textview text.  when you click the button, it launches a new activity that has a datepicker that allows you to choose the date to save in the sharedpreferences file.  when you click ok or press the back button on the update activity, I am trying to get the textview to update with the new date if it was changed but everytime it runs the onresume it does not update the textview text. I have tried invalidating the main linearlayout to have it redraw and that does not work.  I have tried starting the activity with startactivityforresult and that doesnt work even when processing the textview update in onactivityresult.

This is the code for the main class:

```
public class ASMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private LinearLayout llMain;
    private TextView tvDate;
    private Button btnDate;
    private SharedPreferences spSettings;
    private static final String SETTINGS_FILE = "MySettings";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        llMain = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llMain);
        tvDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        btnDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
        spSettings = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_FILE,0);

        tvDate.setText(spSettings.getString("Date", "ERROR"));
        btnDate.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        spSettings = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_FILE, 0);
        tvDate.setText(spSettings.getString("Date", "ERROR"));
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if (v.Id == R.id.btnDate)
      {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, update.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the update.class code:

```
public class update extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private LinearLayout llUpdate;
    private TextView tvLabel;
    private DatePicker dpDate;
    private Button btnOK;
    private SharedPreferences spSettings;
    private static final String SETTINGS_FILE = "MySettings";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

        llUpdate = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llUpdate);
        tvLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLabel);
        dpDate = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpDate);
        btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        spSettings = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_FILE, 0);
        String sTemp = spSettings.getString("Date", "01/01/2013");
        dpDate.updateDate(Integer.parseInt(sTemp.substring(6, 9)), Integer.parseInt(sTemp.substring(0, 1)), Integer.parseInt(sTemp.substring(3, 4)));
        btnOK.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor speSettings = spSettings.edit();
        speSettings.putString("Date", String.valueOf(dpDate.getMonth()) + "/" + String.valueOf(dpDate.getDayOfMonth()) + "/" + String.valueOf(dpDate.getYear()));
        speSettings.commit();

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.Id = R.id.btnOK)
        {
            this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

The textview will update if I click the button again but any changes that I make in the intent I started do not show up once I return to the main activity.

Comment: Just a reminder to other readers, double check the visibility of TextView if not update.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have a similar problem. The  textview is updated must of the times but sometimes it just use the old values. I can see in the log that onResume is called and  sharedpreferences are updated every time.

Answer (score 1):

make change in your `onResume()` like below..

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    spSettings = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_FILE, 0);
    tvDate.setText(spSettings.getString("Date", "ERROR"));
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't work either as it still does not update the tectview after coming back from the intent

Answer (score 0):

After you return from an `Activity` you started with `startActivityForResult()`, you need to handle the results in `onActivityResult()` not `onResume()`.

Follow this example: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Sorry, I've tried that too, I just forgot to leave the ForResult out when I typed the code in to here.  Even if I just use startActivity() it still doesn't update in the onResume()

Comment: Okay so what happens onResume? Does your textView say "ERROR?" Or does it show the date? Maybe you're not saving your settings properly? Post you code in update.class. What results are you expecting to see?

Comment: Once it does update, it shows the date stored in the settings file correctly. The results I am expecting are to have the textview update with the new date after I make a change in the intent that I launch.  I'm on my phone right note but I'll add the update.class code as soon as I get to a computer.  I'll also do a better job of explaining what I've tried.